# Read text box user input and insert into hyperlink using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am learning Javascript.
I want to:

1. Read a user input (a number that is inserted in to a link address)
2. Insert the input into a hyperlink string.
3. Launch the hyperlink.

I am able to read the input and create the string but I cannot get it to launch the website.  The string looks correct, however, I am not sure if the problem is actually the string or that I am not launching it correctly. I am able to find examples of each step, but cannot seem to put them together.

Here is my current code: (can't test the link because I cannot see it).
I am sorry if this doesn't come out correctly.  It look correct when I paste it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function myLink() {
    var numberEntered = document.getElementById("lessNum").value; //Read  input
    var lessonlink =  'http://www.ASmarterWayToLearn.com/js/' + numberEntered + '.html'; //Create link

    window.open(lessonLink); //Go to link

    document.getElementById("theLink").value = lessonLink; // check link address

}
</script>

<!-- Read Lesson number -->
<form>
    Lesson Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lessNum" onBlur="myLink();"><p>

    <!-- Display link for verification -->
    Link:<br>
    <input type="text" id="theLink" style="width: 400px;"><p>
</form>
    <p>
```

Comment: Can you provide us your current code? This may help to understand what you're missing, thanks.

Comment: Does your url string works? Have you tested it by pasting it in your brother url?

Comment: Current code (not working).  Cannot test string because I cannot see it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >

function myLink() {
 var numberEntered = document.getElementById("lessNum").value;
 var lessonlink =  'http://www.ASmarterWayToLearn.com/js/' + numberEntered + '.html'; 
 
 window.open(lessonLink); //Go to link

 document.getElementById("theLink").value = lessonLink; // check link address
  
}
</script>

<!-- Read Lesson number -->
<form>
 Lesson Number:<br>
 <input type="text" id="lessNum" onBlur="myLink();"><p>
 
 <!-- Display link for verification -->
 Link:<br>
 <input type="text" id="theLink" style="width: 400px;"><p>
</form>
 <p>

Answer (score 1):

In Javascipt :

```
window.open(yourString);
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp